# Solve $y'+xy=y^3$

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics

solving it using reduction to linear from Bernoulli equation.
$y'+xy=y^3$.

should I use first 
$u=y^{1-3}$

Then, what will be the remaining procedure.

Answer (score 1):

$u=y^{1-3}=y^{-2}=>y=u^{-0.5}=>y'=-u^{-3/2}u'/2$
$$
\\-u^{-3/2}u'/2+xu^{-1/2}=u^{-3/2}
\\u\equiv0 \;\text or\; u'-2xu=-1
\\u_0'=2xu_0
\\\ln|u_0|=x^2+const
\\u_0=ce^{x^2}(c=const)
\\u=f(x)e^{x^2}
\\u'=f'e^{x^2}+2xfe^{x^2}
\\u'-2xu=f'e^{x^2}=-1
\\f'=e^{-x^2}
\\f=\int e^{-x^2}dx
\\y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{e^{x^2}\int e^{-x^2}dx}}
$$
Answer $y=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{e^{x^2}\int e^{-x^2}dx}}$ or $y\equiv 0$